# concatenating strings at particular position in Python

Tags: python

I have a string as:

```
string1 = '../data/annotation/product_Aca_ma_MBIC11017.txt'
```

It is basically a path for the file that I will use later.

I want to add `string2 = 'fake_'` to `string1` at a particular position, to make it look like:

```
'../data/annotation/fake_product_Aca_ma_MBIC11017.txt'
```

So far, I did:

```
string1 = string2+string1
```

It outputs as:

```
'fake_../data/annotation/product_Aca_ma_MBIC11017.txt'
```

What should I do to add `string2` at a particular position of `string1`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are manipulating paths, so use `os.path` to split and rejoin:

```
dir, filename = os.path.split(string1)
string1 = os.path.join(dir, string2 + filename)
```